# Burninate the workbook tag

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The [workbook](/questions/tagged/workbook) tag should be [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) - even the wiki for this tag says it's excel only:

> A workbook is a native Microsoft Excel spreadsheet file containing discrete workspaces called worksheets on which calculations are performed.

Comment: While many of the questions tagged `workbook` are about Excel, not all of them are.  Most of the rest are simply poorly tagged or are just bad questions to begin with.

Answer (score 4):

There are 87 questions tagged [workbook](/questions/tagged/workbook) and 64 of them are [tagged both workbook and excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/workbook+excel).  I think that calls for a clean-up, not burnination.

Comment: A lot of them not tagged with [tag:excel] are tagged with some sort of Excel sub-tag, like [tag:excel-vba].

Comment: @animuson Good spot.  Definitely a light clean-up effort.